# trying to understand composer

Tags: php, composer-php

This has been frustrating me and I am turning here for help. I understand PHP 4.x very well, and much of PHP 5.x. What I have been having trouble with is Composer.

Please forgive me if this seems like a simple question, but I have frustrated myself trying to figure this out.

I understand that it replaces `include();` and `require();`, and it can load all the PHP scripts in a file (as opposed to listing each one individually).

I am in a shared hosting environment and cannot (at least so far) Composer, which is only adding to my frustration.

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": “php/webapp”,
    "type": "project",
    "description": "A php web application”,
    "keywords": [“php”],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/xxx”,
    "license": "MIT",
    "require-dev": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",

    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": ["application/engine/“, "application/calculations/“] }
    }
}
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Is it possible to install in a shared hosting environment?
2. Can someone point me to a good online tutorial, article, white paper, etc. that explains Composer?
3. How would I hard code the autoloaded files, in PHP, from the composer.json file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, off topic, off topic; side note curly quotes!?!?!!?

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't replace include() and require. The primary goal of composer it's managing dependencies of your application, so you can reuse some popular and well-tested code. Also it provides autoloading capabilities for your application. I think it will be useful for you to take a look on the section of PHP documentation about [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), besides composer docs, which is really good. Also you can find some good stuff on those topics on youtube. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes as long as your requirements are met by the server's PHP installation / plugins / etc. Your hosting company can help you with that but in most cases it is not a problem. If you don't have access to Composer on the command line you can [install it locally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally) in your project.
2. The official [basic usage guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) is a good way to get started
3. The [autoloading section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) explains how to get it kickstarted with a single `require` statement

Browse for interesting looking packages on [Packagist](http://packagist.org/) and use `composer` on the command-line to install, upgrade and remove them. Click on the Github link for any package to see good documentation, sample code and tests.

When you come to commit your code to  a repository be sure to check Composer's docs on `.gitignore` additions.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

1. Composer can be installed on a shared hosting environment. But the question might end up being how are you using it in the shared hosting environment. If you are doing active development in the shared hosting environment, then you might want to make sure you have command line access so you can `composer install` and `composer update`.  If development is being done locally, and delivered to the shared environment, then just deliver the code that has been installed. The actual composer.phar will not be necessary.
2. What's `good` is a bit of an opinion piece. The getcomposer.org website is the source on how to use it best, with https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md being a really good start.
3. Not sure exactly what you are after here.  To make the autoloaded files from composer accessible, `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'` is all you should need. Refer to https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading.

As @Dagon mentioned, you have some curly quotes in your .json, where regular double quotes should be.